# OpenGraph Watch Action Don't Appear Anywhere

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have pages that type's are `video.other` (with valid open graph meta tags) and try to publish watch action. Using Javascript SDK, publishing with this code:

```
FB.api('/me/video.watches', 'POST', { 
        video: 'my_video_url_is_here', 
        'fb:explicitly_shared' : true
    }, 
    function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response.error);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
        }
});
```

The response is:

```
{"id" : "a_fb_id"}
```

Although there is no error, i can't see the action in my timeline or activity log page and can't access with this url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/a_fb_id
```

With the url `https://graph.facebook.com/a_fb_id?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`, i get this json data:

```
{
    "id": "a_fb_id", 
    "from": {
        "name": "MY_NAME", 
        "id": "MY_FACEBOOK_ID"
    }, 
    "start_time": "2013-12-04T09:50:58+0000", 
    "end_time": "2013-12-04T09:50:58+0000", 
    "publish_time": "2013-12-04T09:50:58+0000", 
    "application": {
        "name": "MY_APP_NAME", 
        "namespace": "MY_APP_NAMESPACE", 
        "id": "MY_APP_ID"
    }, 
    "data": {
        "video": {
            "id": "video_fb_og_id", 
            "url": "MY_VIDEO_URL", 
            "type": "video.other", 
            "title": "MY_VIDEO_TITLE"
        }
    }, 
    "type": "video.watches", 
    "no_feed_story": false, 
    "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
    }, 
    "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
    }
}
```

This is my application's `Watch` common action type (built-in) approval status:
[image: Approval Status]

Everything seems ok but there is no activty about the action. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you see it on the page ''https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity'' ?

Comment: @SebastienC. unfortunately no.

Comment: that's strange... a permission issue or a malformed video object would have returned an error object. Could it be because of the '10 seconds limitation'? I've read somewhere that facebook requires users to watch at least 10 seconds of video before allowing to post a video.watch action. Here you have an end test equal to the start date...

Comment: @SebastienC. i try to publish with start and end date but same result. I will resubmit action and wait.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to access it the following way as stated in the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#read):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/video.watches?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Please notice that you'll need to have the right OpenGraph permission as described here ("user_actions.video") as described in the docs as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/open-graph-permissions/

Comment: Yes, i can see the action list, it appears here but still don't exist in activity log or timeline. I resubmit action and it was approved.

Comment: Did you check the "Include 'Only me' activities checkbox"? I think (depending on how you gave your permissions to the app) that the Opengraph actions might get published in "private" mode. These are not shown in the activity log by default, at least for my profile

Comment: Yes i checked it too but same result.

Comment: OK, might be a FB bug, I'm not sure. Can you elaborate why the Activity Log is important for you? At least for me it seems that if you can see it via /me/video.watches the OpenGraph action was successfully published

Comment: If it don't appears to Facebook user profiles, it is no matter of publishing action :)

Comment: Well, at least this I understood... For the virality effect, it is from my perspective much more important if you can see the action in the friend's newsfeed, rather than my own Activity Log. Have you checked whether friends can see your actions in their newsfeed (I know this depends on the EdgeRank mechanism as well)...?

Comment: Yes i checked, no body see the action.

Comment: Is there a sample app I can try?